# Set a single setTimeout in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I'm building a multiplication testing app, and I want each question to have an 8-second countdown that resets when an answer is ended. My problem is that when my component re-renders another instance of the setTimeout is created, meaning I get a two-second countdown, then 3 second etc.

What would be the correct way to handle this?

My component:

```
class Question extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            answer: "",
            correct: false,
            timer: 8
        } 

        this.countDownTrack = null;

        this.checkAnswer = this.checkAnswer.bind(this);
    }

    countDown() {
        let number = this.state.timer;
        if (number > 0 && this.state.correct === false){
            number--
            this.setState({
                timer: number
            })
        } else {
            this.props.sendAnswer(this.state.answer, this.props.randIndex);
            this.setState({
                timer: 8
            })
        }
    }

    //what we want is for there to be a single setTimeout

    CountDownHandle = () => {
        this.countDownTrack = setTimeout(()=>{
            this.countDown();
        },1000)
    }


    checkAnswer = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.sendAnswer(this.state.answer, this.props.randIndex);
        this.setState({
            answer: "",
            timer: 8
        })
    }


    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            answer: event.target.value
        })
    }


    render(){

        this.CountDownHandle();

        let countShow;
        countShow = this.state.timer;

            return (
                <div className="Question">
                <h1>What is</h1>
                <h1><span id="table1">{parseInt(this.props.no1)}</span> X <span id="table2">{parseInt(this.props.no2)}</span>?</h1>
                <form action="" onSubmit={this.checkAnswer}>
                <input autoComplete="off" type="text" name="answer" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.answer}/>
                </form>
                <p>{countShow}</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }


export default Question;
```

Comment: You need to create the `setTimeout()` in response to an event, e.g. "starting a new question". If there's no specific event/handler like that, then make one. I assume this is designed to have multiple questions, so there would be (or will be) some event related to beginning a new question.

Comment: Hi Jayce, thank you for your comment - the way I’m doing it currently is when the user submits a question it changes the state in the parent component which triggers a re-render of the props and so of the Question component. Do you think my setTimeout should be part of the ‘submitting answer’ method?

Comment: Well that depends, when they submit an answer does that also start the new question at the same time? Or does something else have to happen between them submitting an answer and the next question starting? Also, what if the user doesn't submit an answer and the timer runs out? Does the app automatically trigger the "submit an answer" event?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll go through it and check exactly where I'm delegating the different actions

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear timeout re-rendering the component using this function:

```
        clearTimeout(this.trackingTimer);
```

It maybe a part of else code block in countDown().

Answer (score 0):

Remember to clear the timeout when the component is unmount via ComponentWillUnmount. 
That will make sure there is no unwanted timer running on the background.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues with your code structure:

1. If you want to show a visible countdown (eg. 8,7,6,...)

> use "setInterval"

rather than "setTimeout"

2. Place the timer event trigger function outside of the render function, like in the componentDidMount, a button click, input focus, or a response to a singular action.

Also, to control the timeout to be singular, check if an instance exists 1st.

```
if(!this.countDownTrack)
  this.countDownTrack = setInterval(
   ()=>{

     this.countDown();
     if(this.state.timer < 1)
        clearInterval(this.trackingTimer);


    },1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with this, I'll try and mop it up and get it working